# Global connection string good or evil

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

connections.php

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    $GLOBALS['connection'] = $connection;
```

all_other_files.php

```
     require_once 'connections.php';
     //In all of my sql prepare statements
     mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS['connection'], $query);
```

Is it good or bad in terms of security?

Comment: Security wise I can't really see why it'd be better or worse than anything else, but why not just use `$connection` which looks like it'd still be in scope also?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I understand that. I have all my queries in separate functions. I need to pass conn string to all the functions. To avoid that I store it in the global.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$GLOBALS` is a bad thing, and it's not really how we do it now. The good option would be to use a Singleton class or if you don't develop your website in OOP (which is bad), just a variable in your include.

Comment: `Is it good or bad in terms of security?` Why is it less safe, please explain

Comment: Why is not developing your website in OOP bad ? Why should it be a singleton (that's not the only option out there )?

Comment: Because while you're in college, you should stick to OOP as much as possible. :D

Comment: Not really a security concern but if you can avoid initialize it (since it's now JIT), then, do it.

And because it's better to take profit of OOP possibility, sclability, readability and everything ending with "ibility".

Comment: @Sakuto That doesn't mean procedural programming is bad. And if with JIT you're refering to just in time compiler, PHP doesn't use that HHVM uses it.

Comment: Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php#104666 plus as OP said, he have a lot of function, which is, well, princip of OOP.